# how to upload picture and store in database

Tags: php, mysql, image, image-uploading

```
$image = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

$image = mysql_real_escape_string($image);


mysql_query("UPDATE ngc set pic='" . $image "' WHERE username='" . $_SESSION["username"] . "'");


<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Upload Image :<input type="file" name="image" id="file">
<br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update!" class="btnSubmit">

</form>
```

i want to upload image to database..

Comment: Nabin, use `mysqli` instead of `mysql` because it's deprecated by php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this very nice example here: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-mysql-blob/
Also see this image gallery example here: http://www.anyexample.com/programming/php/php_mysql_example__image_gallery_(blob_storage).xml

BLOBs are data types in MySql database which can help you store image files in database directly.

Although a better way would be to store the file on the disk and store the path of that variable in the database.

Answer (score 0):

get the Content of the file and save in database;

```
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
```

Mysql:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `product_images` (`id`, `image`) VALUES ('1', '{$image}')";
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you want to save the entire image into the database , you must have the pic attribute type set to BLOB , here you have two options , either save the entire image into database , or save the name after uploading the images into a specified folder with a unique name each , so you can retrieve the images by name into this directory.